# Set background color for paragraph using iText Java

Tags: java, itext

I'm working with iText PDF Java and having problems when I want to set background color for each paragraph.

[image]

In this PDF, I have 3 paragraphs with 3 different color.

I have try using Chunk but it not meet with my target.

Chunk only set background for text not paragraph.

Please give advise to do it

Comment: Perhaps this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020658/how-can-i-add-a-background-color-to-my-pdf-text-using-itext-to-create-it-with

Comment: @AchinthaGunasekara I just try this but it only set background for text not paragraph as my picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is using table and set background color for each cell.

Comment: That's a good answer. I was also going to answer that. An alternative would be to use page events, but the code to achieve the same result using `PdfPTable` is much easier.